# Json parsing in array java

Tags: java, json

I am new to *JSON* parsing and I would need your kind help to understand how to parse a *JSON* object inside an `Array`.

My *JSON* structure `log` is below:

```
{A:"text",B:"text",C:[{T:"Text",D:{E:"Text",F:{G:"time"}},H:{I:"200"},J:{K:{L:53,M:2.2},N:"Text"},P:{Q:"Time"}}]}
```

log is my input *JSON* as above.

```
JSONObject logJson = (JSONObject) JSONSerializer.toJSON( log );
String a = logJson.getString("A");
String b = logJson.getString("B");
```

Now question is how do I parse into the `Array` and get `JSONObject`. I am using `net.sf` API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, I think your json format is invalid.

The "key" must stand in " as well e.g.
`"A":"text"`

You can get the "C" Array by using `JSONArray jsonArray = logJson.getJSONArray("C");`

On the array you can iterate:

```
for(int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++)
{
    JSONObject obj = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks.. But I mean the key can be without "

Comment: Ok, I doublechecked, according to the json specification its invalid, according to different implementations (eg.g javascript) it "might" be valid.

Comment: with your above code I can get the value of C, but how do I get the values of D, E , F , G ???

Comment: The same way as before... If its an object `obj.getJSONObject("D");` if its an array obj.getJSONArray("D"); The structure of this json string is pretty awkward, so it's very inconvenient to access all JSON objects

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will help ::

```
    JSONObject objonthwiseClaimJSON = JSONObject.fromString(strJSONMonthwiseClaim);

    JSONArray objDateWiseClaimJSONArr = objonthwiseClaimJSON.getJSONArray("dateWiseClaimList");

 for(int dtwclaim=0; dtwclaim<objDateWiseClaimJSONArr.length();dtwclaim++)
{
                 JSONObject objDateWiseClaimJSONObject =(JSONObject) objDateWiseClaimJSONArr.get(dtwclaim);
                 String dcnid = (String) objDateWiseClaimJSONObject.get("dcnid");
                 String remark = (String) objDateWiseClaimJSONObject.get("remark");
    }
```

In your situation ::

```
JSONObject logJson = (JSONObject) JSONSerializer.toJSON( log );
String a = logJson.getString("A");
String b = logJson.getString("B");
JSONArray c = logJson.getJSONArray("C"); // If C is not an array, just a plain object

for(int i =0;i<c.length();i++)
{
... // 

}
```

Comment: Ok. But how do I traverse into the jsonobjects inside the array ?

Comment: @user1677986: Have updated my answer, please check if that has helped

Comment: Ok... This helped me to understand retreving jsonobject inside array, but how do I get the json object, like in the example        C:[{T:"Text",D:{E:"Text",F:{G:"time"}},

Comment: @user1677986: PLease check now

Comment: In my case C is an array and I want to also print other values like E, F, G and so on.